# Cant correct upload file it says no file found for upload

Tags: c#, api

im trying to create method who can upload file from special path to API link, but when i run application its says no file for upload has been added, so i cant understand, where is problem, i think maybe this line is not working correct bellow

requestUploadFileToDocument.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

My full code for method

```
var ConKey = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["ConKey"];
        var AddFile = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["AddFile"];
        var Document_IDSTflow = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["Document_IDSTflow"];
        var file = ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["file"];

        string UploadFileToDocumentUrl = String.Format(AddFile + "Document_ID=" + Document_IDSTflow + "&key=" + ConKey);

        ASCIIEncoding encoder = new ASCIIEncoding();
        byte[] data = encoder.GetBytes(file);

        HttpWebRequest requestUploadFileToDocument = WebRequest.Create(UploadFileToDocumentUrl) as HttpWebRequest;
        requestUploadFileToDocument.Method = "POST";
        requestUploadFileToDocument.ContentType = "multipart/form-data";
        requestUploadFileToDocument.ContentLength = data.Length;

        requestUploadFileToDocument.GetRequestStream().Write(data, 0, data.Length);

        var httpResponse = (HttpWebResponse)requestUploadFileToDocument.GetResponse();

        using (var streamReader = new StreamReader(httpResponse.GetResponseStream()))
        {
            var result2 = streamReader.ReadToEnd();
            DocumentInfo DocumentInfoJsonData = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<DocumentInfo>(result2);
            if (DocumentInfoJsonData.Status.IsRequestSuccessful == true)
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Metode (POST) - OK");
            }
            else
            {
                Console.WriteLine("Metode (POST) - ERROR");
                Console.WriteLine("\n" + "Error info: " + result2 + "\n");
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

Okey, i resolve this by my self after some wasted days :D

```
HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
            MultipartFormDataContent form = new MultipartFormDataContent();
            HttpContent content = new StringContent("fileToUpload");
            form.Add(content, "fileToUpload");
            
            var stream = new FileStream(FileLocation, FileMode.Open);
            content = new StreamContent(stream);
            content.Headers.ContentDisposition = new ContentDispositionHeaderValue("form-data")
            {
                Name = DocName,
                FileName = FileNameExtension
            };
            form.Add(content);
            HttpResponseMessage response = null;
            
            response = client.PostAsync(UploadFileToDocumentUrl, form).Result;
```